# Android Google MapV2 , npe on Android 2.3.x

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have implemented `GoogleMapV2` as a view in `XML` in my fragment overriding all the lifecycle methods both for my Fragment and MapView within them.

With these settings everything is working fine on devices with `Android OS 4.x` and even on `Androi 2.2`  but `GoogleMap` always returns null when I run my code on `Android 2.3.6` based device.

Any inputs on what I might be doing wrong?.

Comment: is there any configuration difference between the 2.3.6 device and the 4.x devices? (Google Play version, etc)

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, on the device i was testing , Google Play Account was not signed in, Once i signed in , the error was resolved.